# NodeJS Issue for Amazon Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on a school project, and am trying to get data from a URL for integration with my Alexa Skill. I am definitely a NodeJS beginner, and don't have much of a background with HTML or JSON either.

My school has an "API" for our transportation system here: https://prtstatus.wvu.edu/api/
A sample case with a time stamp is here: https://prtstatus.wvu.edu/api/1501906657/?format=json

In my code, I'm trying to get parse as JSON the string from the get from the URL, but am running into issues formatting it so that the "message:" portion of the string will be passed on. Here is the code for my intent in my AWS Lambda:

```
'getPRTStatus': function() {
    var date = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var http = require('http');
    var https = require('https');

    var options = {
        host: 'https://prtstatus.wvu.edu',
        path: '/api/'+date+'/?format=json'
    };
    var object;
    var callback = function(response) {
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);
            object = JSON.parse(str);
        });
    }

    https.request(options, callback).end();
    this.attributes.speechOutput = this.t(object.message);
    this.attributes.repromptSpeech = this.t(object.message);
    this.emit(':ask', this.attributes.speechOutput, this.attributes.repromptSpeech);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things that need to be addressed in the code:

1. In options, you don't need to specify the protocol. Per the http documentation, the options host should just be the domain name. So in this case it will be "prtstatus.wvu.edu"
2. The object.message is being used before the callback gets finished. Hence you would probably see error like "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined". What needs to happen is that the 3 lines (this.attributes...) be a part of the callback itself.